# I am using Decorators , But It Returns none , why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

**I've written this code but my output comes 'None' , Why not comming Correct output**

```
def decor_func(any_func):
      def wrapper_func(*args , **kwargs):
        if all([type(arg) == int for arg in args]):
              any_func(*args , **kwargs)

  return wrapper_func

@decor_func
def add(*args):
    total = 0
    for i in args:
        total += i

    return total


print(add(1, 2, 5, 6))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your wrapper function does not return anything:

```
def decor_func(any_func):
    def wrapper_func(*args , **kwargs):
        if all([type(arg) == int for arg in args]):
            return any_func(*args , **kwargs)  # return the result!
    return wrapper_func
```

Not returning implicitly returns `None`. It would still return `None` if any of the arguments weren't of type `int`. So, meaningfully handling that case, using `isinstance` for the type check, and using a generator expression instead of a list comprehension would be 3 further improvements:

```
def decor_func(any_func):
    def wrapper_func(*args):
        if all(isinstance(arg, int) for arg in args):
            return any_func(*args , **kwargs)
        raise TypeError
    return wrapper_func
```